# Bootstrap custom slide transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I make the current Bootstrap carousel image stay still while the next slide moves in over the top of it?  The text can slide off like normal, but I would like for the image to stay put.

Here's an example on bootply: http://www.bootply.com/mfKPouoFhH

Comment: So it's basically just a change of the animation? Before and after the transitions it should be as it is?

Comment: @maraca Yep.  I have been looking at the fade in/fade out transition tutorials as a starting point since I posted this, but no luck yet.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a jFiddle whith only the relevant data where people can make some experiments

Comment: Ok, I'll get that done in the morning. (Gotta run)  Thanks for your responses!

Comment: Here's an example on bootply: http://www.bootply.com/mfKPouoFhH